# VBA code to insert tables from a different workbook from multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, automation, outlook, automated-tests

I have a mismatch error in my code below: I have a workbook to run the mail automation and a different workbook to get the table details from.

```vb
Sub Send_Mails_To_Drafts()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send_Mails")
    
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Path.xlsm")
    
    Dim Pointer As Long
    Dim table As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim OA As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    Dim sign As String
    
    Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    
    Dim last_row As Integer
    last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    
    For i = 2 To last_row
        
        For Pointer = 3 To wb2.Sheets.Count
            
            table = wb2.Sheets(Pointer).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            
            Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
            msg.To = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
            msg.cc = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
            msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
            msg.Display
            sign = msg.htmlbody
            msg.htmlbody = "Dear Supervisor, <br/<br/ See below the table of your least utilized units based on Work Order reporting for the last week. Please note that we have reduced the period to  <b<ulast week only</u</b  to avoid confusion of previous assignments. <br/<br/ This list is limited to the <b<uworst performing 10 units under 75%.</u</b Our goal is to increase utilization on these units, correct any misassigned units, or return any not-needed units. The spreadsheet attached provides detail on reporting. If you have any questions about this report, please let your manager know. <br/<br/ <b<font color=green Expanse uses KPA to assign equipment to supervisors, to shop repairs, and between branches. If any of your equipment is not assigned correctly, please contact your manager to do the correct assignment in KPA.</b</font" & table & sign

            If sh.Range("D" & i).Value < "" Then
                msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("D" & i).Value
            End If
            
            On Error GoTo errHandler
            'Mark the email as sent in the Excel sheet
            sh.Range("F" & i).Value = "Sent"
            
errHandler:
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "An error occurred while saving the draft: " & Err.Description
            End If
        
        Next Pointer
    
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "All the mails have been sent successfully"

End Sub
```

Comment: You should always provide the line that throws the error. I assume the line `table = wb2.Sheets(Pointer).Range("A1").CurrentRegion` throws an error: you define `table` as String, but `CurrentRegion` is a `Range`. This statement will only work if `CurrentRegion` contains only one cell (but it's likely that this is not what you want).

Comment: That's right @FunThomas, can I use other Variables other than String or Range that would still work? Thank you!